# How to read original data from excel using poi and java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Suppose i have a data like this in a cell 123,876,3434,124, when i read the value from cell it's removing the comma and reading the value like this 1238763434124. so i want to print the same value in the cell.

Comment: So what is your question !!!??? and what have you tried ? Refer [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Answer (score 0):

You should try [HSSFCell.html#getCellStyle()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getCellStyle%28%29), it will return the cell style information which you can use in your code.